# Restore Moodle Backup issues: error reading from database

Tags: moodle

I am trying to restore a backup of Moodle version 2.7 with PHP 5.5 and MySQL 5.5 from one server to another server with Moodle 3.9 and PHP 7.4 and MySQL 8.0. But I am getting the following error:
[image]

I even tried the to change `@@default_storage_engine` to `@@storage_engine` in /lib/dml/mysqli_native_moodle_database.php but still not working. I also verified the disk space. There is enough space on the disk.

Comment: You're probably going to need to turn on debugging https://docs.moodle.org/en/Debugging to see a more meaningful error message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow an upgrade path from Moodle 2.7

https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/Upgrading_FAQ#How_do_I_upgrade_from_1.9.x_to_3.11.3F

First install Moodle 2.7.20 on the new server and restore the database.

Then upgrade to Moodle 3.2.9

Then you can upgrade to Moodle 3.9.x

Note that you will need to upgrade any additional plugins that were installed too. I'd recommend doing this at each upgrade stage for each version.

If you haven't already, you will also need to back up the site data folder at the same time as the database backup. The site data folder contains uploaded files, these are not stored in the database. As well as custom languages.

https://docs.moodle.org/39/en/Upgrading